# Tomcat performance degradation during Parallel Deployments

Tags: tomcat, deployment, resources, limit

We've noticed that a deployment of a new application version in Tomcat (using Parallel Deployments) the deployment process consumes all available CPU resources. This drives the request response times of this app to an unacceptable value and means an impact of several minutes per application server.

Is there a way to limit/throttle/prioritize the resources spent on deploying the new app version so that the old app version can continue to serve requests at an acceptable response time?

We are using Tomcat 8.5.20.

Comment: What's the behavior if you don't use parallel deployments? I'm assuming that you're deploying several applications at once, as you mention parallel deployment - is this common, will many be updated at the same time commonly or can you just sequentialize them?

Comment: We have just one app per Tomcat. Note that Parallel Deployment means running different versions of the same app to achieve zero-downtime as described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment

Comment: Oops - talk about context misleading. Had a discussion a day before that totally led me in a different direction. While I've never used parallel deployment, I've been fascinated by the possibility. However, I'm usually working through loadbalancers to take one of the machines out of the balancing for updates, so other machines take over. Or, on low-traffic sites: Just do it. I'll leave the answer to others then.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Tomcat allocates a single thread to application deployment in this case. (You can configure Tomcat to deploy apps in parallel during the startup process but even there there default is a single thread).

If you have multiple cores available to the Tomcat process, a single thread should not be able to consume all available CPU. At most, it should consume a single core. That suggests the application start-up code is multi-threaded. I'd suggest using a profilier to take a look at what is going on with a view to possibly changing the application's initialisation code.

Tomcat could add an option to control the thread priority of the thread doing the application deployment but I don't know enough about the impact of changing that to weigh the risks and benefits.